# Historical test results for A/B & MV testing

Tags: content-testing

During an A/B test, I was able to see results such as number of visitors to each version, conversions rates etc.

But now when the test has ended, I cannot see any of the data. I have looked at Historical Tests in both Experience Editor and Experience Optimization with no luck.

This is what I see now:

[image]

This is what I saw during the test:

[image]

Where can I access the test results dialogue after an A/B test is completed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else is still looking for the detailed results on completed A/B tests in older versions of Sitecore and finds this question - this functionality has been introduced in Sitecore 9.1 ([release notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/91/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2091%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes)) and previous versions did not have such capability.

Starting from 9.1 you can navigate to the historical tests list and click a test to see its details and results ([documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/test-lists.html)):

[image: Completed test results]